# Broadcasting with dot product

Tags: numpy, broadcast

I'm trying to solve a set of dot products. Currently, the best way I found is using this loop.

```
for i in range(n):
    u[:,:,i] = np.dot(K[i,:,:], v[:,:,i])
```

Could someone help me out to solve this by broadcasting or another faster method?

Thanks very much

Comment: What are the shapes of K and v? Or what do they represent?

Comment: You don't want `broadcasting`.  `dot` does broadcasting of the leading dimensions, `u[i,j,:,:]=np.dot( K[i,:,;], v[j,:,:])`.  `matmul` treats them as 'batch' dimensions, `u[i,:,:] = np.dot([K[i,:,:], v[i,:,:])`.

Comment: @swag2198 the shape of K is n x b x c and the shape of v is c x d x n.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't necessarily want to do broadcasting, just somehow avoid the for loop if possible.

Comment: If you don't want do the transpose required by `np.matmul`, you could explore using `np.einsum`.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm sorry but I don't understand what you meant. Can you write the code to do this using np.matmul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround is:

```
u = np.matmul(K, v.transpose(2, 0, 1))
u = u.transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

I am assuming `K` has shape n x b x c and `v` has shape c x d x n. Transposing `v` like that makes it of shape n x c x d, which makes it possible to perform n matrix multiplications of input shapes b x c and c x d and the result is n x b x d.

Finally, you also need to transpose `u` to get it in the desired shape of b x d x n.

Answer (score 0):

A more intuitively readable solution than manually shuffling around axes would be to use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to calculate your results:

```py
import numpy as np

n = 7
b = 8
c = 11
d = 4

K = np.random.rand(n, b, c)
v = np.random.rand(c, d, n)

u = np.matmul(K, v.transpose(2, 0, 1)).transpose(1, 2, 0)
w = np.einsum('nbc,cdn->bdn', K, v)

print(np.allclose(u, w)) # True
```